# Battery Drain or Memory Issue

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to create an App.. I used Alarm manager to run in every 1 minute so that it could run a AlarmReciever and can do a network task and Updating UI from Background.. Alarm Manager is firing in Activity.. I Just want to know will it affect battery by doing so? Also Like to know whether everytime i opened the activity will the AlarmManager will trigger. If so how can i tackle that situation..

I searched Everywhere most of the solution is to do AlarmManager rather than service as it will trigger even if app is killed..

My AlarmManager Code:

```
Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                    cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, AlarmReceiver.class);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, intent, 0);
                    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Running network every minute will drain your battery very fast and you should strongly think about a different aproach, e.g. Push from the server if there is new data. Maybe check out android performance patterns, there are multiple videos about networking https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE

Comment: But i have to check go to a link where any changes is there and get the result from server.. Even if there is new data i should need to go to the api link for changes right..

Comment: As @DavidMedenjak said, at this frequency you should use Firebase Cloud Messaging to push an indicator to your client when there is a change on the server, then your app does a pull to get the data. (Instead of using the Alarm to wake the network radios.)